# Bug: media query max-width plus Windows 10

Tags: css, media-queries, windows-10

`@media (max-width: 767px)` should affects on 767px and less, but I was having problems with it because it wasn't applying my CSS on 767px. After a long while testing I noticed is working fine on Windows 7 but not on Windows 10.

I have Chrome (v54.0.2840.71 m) in both OS. I tested it in Firefox as well and I've the same problem if I run it on Win10.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kamae/n3td7yy2/2/).

As you can see, the `min-width` is working fine, so I can fix it reverting my CSS and working from lowest resolution to highest... It's just an annoying solution. I was wondering if someone knows another way to fix that. I have tried `max-device-width` also but still working wrong...

Thanks

Comment: working fine here on windows 10 with chrome 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit): https://jsfiddle.net/av5511vn/ and with your script too

Comment: really? your fiddle is not working to me using win10 (64-bit) same Chrome version O.o... Are you resizing the fiddle frame till 767px appears on top? Like in this screenshot: http://s21.postimg.org/a0gzrg4mf/windows10max_Width.jpg

Comment: I've modified yours to include the current px on top, because the browser inspector on fiddle is not telling you how many px there are in the "result frame": https://jsfiddle.net/Kamae/av5511vn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE (03-Jun-2019)**

As pointed out by [sKopheK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426210/skophek), it seems now with `max-width: 767.9px` would be enough, otherwise it will round it to `768px`.

---

**Original Answer**

Well, thanks to [this link](http://damienclarke.me/code/posts/those-1px-gaps-between-media-queries-can-be-a-problem) posted by [Vladimir Pittner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7291823/vladimir-pittner) I found a valid solution. One of the comments says to put the `max-width` value as a float. So instead of `767px` you can put `767.999px` and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: hi, found a glitch with this approach as `only screen and (max-width: 767.999px) and (min-width: 480px)` is applied for window size of **768px**. changing the media query parameter to 767.9px fixed that, but it feels a bit hackish and fragile

Comment: Yeah you are right, I had to do the same a few months ago. I did not remember this post was here, I will update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://damienclarke.me/code/posts/those-1px-gaps-between-media-queries-can-be-a-problem

> **Avoiding the cause**. 
>   An easy fix is to only ever use min-width or max-width media queries. This is often a healthy side effect from having a true mobile first approach to writing CSS rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I know that **Avoiding the cause** could fix it, I already said that: `As you can see, the min-width is working fine, so I can fix it reverting my CSS and working from lowest resolution to highest... It's just an annoying solution. I was wondering if someone knows another way to fix that.`

Comment: The point is Windows 10 is ignoring the max-width value and it's only working if you use the value as a float rounded at the next value (basically adding `.999`). I upvote your answer because I found that in the comments of your link.